# Want to combine date and time in a column using R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, time-series, arima

I have the following dataframe

```
 Date             Time
10/03/2014       12.00.00
11/03/2014       13.00.00
12/03/2014       14.00.00
```

I want to create one single column as follows

```
DT
10/03/2014 12.00.00
11/03/2014 13.00.00
12/03/2014 14.00.00
```

when I run

```
data$DT <- as.POSIXct(paste(x$Date, x$Time), format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I get a column DT with all NA values.

Comment: change your format from "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" to "%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S"

Comment: Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 6):

```
Data$DT <- as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(data$Date, data$Time)), format="%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S")
```

OR

```
data$Time <- gsub('\\.',':',data$Time)
data$Date <- gsub('/','-',data$Date)

data$DT <- as.POSIXct(as.character(paste(data$Date, data$Time)), format="%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 3):

This should be a very common problem, hence contributing with a reproducible answer using *dplyr*:

```
## reproducible example
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
DF <- data.frame(Date = c("10/03/2014", "11/03/2014", "12/03/2014"),
                 Time = c("12.00.00", "13.00.00", "14.00.00"))

DF_DT <- DF %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = paste(Date, Time)) %>% 
  mutate(across('DateTime', ~ as.POSIXct(.x, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H.%M.%S")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the package `lubridate`:

```
data$DT <- with(data, ymd(Date) + hms(Time))
```

If you want the column to be a `POSIXct`, do the following after that:

```
data$DT <- as.POSIXct(data$DT)
```